# React native + expo большой размер apk

Tags: android, react-native, build

С помощью exp build:android скомпилировал дефолтный проект с несколькими надписями. Получаю apk размером 25.5 метров. Недавно начал пользоваться ra и поэтому не знаю норма ли это и как уменьшить размер apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это нормальный размер apk для пустого Expo-приложения. Создатели [объясняют](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/why-not-expo.html) такой большой размер тем, что в apk запакованы библиотеки для Expo API, не зависимо нужны они вам или нет. Если вам необходимо "тонкое" приложение - Expo не лучший выбор. Как вариант, вы можете мигрировать свое приложение из Expo в React Native как описано в [этой статье](https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640)(на английском).